# PayPal SDK Typescript types - do they fully exist?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the PayPal SDK which seems to be split to different packages, each with their own (or missing) Typescript types.

`@paypal/checkout-server-sdk` has no proper types, and there is `@types/paypal__checkout-server-sdk` to help but it also misses types and has errors.

`@paypal/payouts-sdk` has `@types/paypal__payouts-sdk` which looks ok (but I didn't try it in practice yet).

And finally `@paypal/react-paypal-js` which comes with its own types.

This combination of type sources has conflicts and almost entirely misses all of the return types of the API calls, and I can't tell what each API actually expects to get or return.

Do I need to go and manually create types reading the SDK docs (assuming they are updated), and keep blindly converting types between mine and the ones from these packages?

Answer (score 0):

The server SDK and the client-side SDK run in entirely different places so separate them in your mind.

@paypal/checkout-sever-sdk was likely written without types, and hasn't been meaningfully updated in awhile. It's a minimal SDK, and in fact the current documentation on developer.paypal.com just points to doing direct REST API calls on the server side (no SDK), obtaining your own access_token with the client ID and secret.

If using react, the official @paypal/react-paypal-js is the way to go for **the client-side approval flow portion of the implementation**. It does not do its own server-based PayPal API calls. If you want to see a good example of createOrder and onApprove functions you can use (this example is pure JS but the fetch calls work in react as well) that call a server backend with fetch, see https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

( Note there a similar full stack example https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ but it currently doesn't have code for client-side error handling when the capture doesn't succeed , so the Smart Buttons Demo link is a better template for these functions )

Comment: Those are useful links for the beginning, but I have all my PayPal stuff working already after a lot of googling and testing. With that being said, I would really like to have types for the return values of API calls, and the mismatch between definitions of the same objects (such as `Item` and `PurchaseUnit`) makes it hard to say what objects I actually have in the different stages. Either way I suppose I'll have to make my own if I want them :/